# Compare values from database query and Regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: regex, jdbc, jmeter

How can I compare values that I get from a database query to a value that I get from a regular expression extractor?

I am testing a web service that is connected to a database and I want to check if the results I get from the web service are equal to the results in the database.

Example:

I am connected to a database and I write the query to check the condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items
```

From this query I get the value = 100

After that I call the method on the web service to get the items from the database and I count the unique IDs of the items using a regular expression extractor and I get the result.

```
Items_matchNr=100
```

So, I want to compare:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items == Items_matchNr
```

Is it possible to compare these 2 values in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare 2 values using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) like

1. Put Response Assertion i.e. after the Regular Expression Extractor
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable -> First JMeter Variable name (note, without ${}, just name)
   - Pattern matching rules: Equals
   - Patterns to test: Second JMeter Variable, this time surrounded by ${}

[image: Response Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally setting JMeter samplers results using assertions

Comment: So the problem now is:

The Regular Expression Extractor does not return only the Items_matchNr but also returns all the items it found.

So, in the response assertion I get the following error code:

Assertion error: true
Assertion failure: false

Assertion failure message: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: It appears that the value you're getting from the DB doesn't come in String format so you will have to do some scripting to pull it out of the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide for examples of programmatic JDBC test elements result set access

Comment: Thanks. The problem was even though the result from the query was a number, JMeter stores it as an ArrayList